# Ошибка С2280 При объявление конструктора копирования

Tags: c++, ооп

Пишу класс Дом со всеми его характеристиками, как только начинаю делать конструктор копирования, так сразу выскакивает ошибка С2280 с текстом
Ошибка  C2280   "Home &Home::operator =(const Home &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию DZ3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\list    1284

```
class Home
{

public:
    Home() {}; // по умолчанию
    Home(size_t _Home_Floor, size_t _House_Number, size_t _Home_Apart, size_t _Home_Sitizens, bool _bHave_Basement, bool _bHave_Parking, bool _bOn_Left)
        :Home_Floor(_Home_Floor), House_Number(_House_Number), Home_Apart(_Home_Apart), Home_Sitizens(_Home_Sitizens), bHave_Basement(_bHave_Basement), bHave_Parking(_bHave_Parking),
        bOn_Left(_bOn_Left)
    {}
    Home(const Home& other)
    {
        this->bHave_Basement = other.bHave_Basement;
        this->bHave_Parking = other.bHave_Parking;
        this->bOn_Left = other.bOn_Left;
        this->Home_Apart = other.Home_Apart;
        this->Home_Floor = other.Home_Floor;
        this->Home_Sitizens = other.Home_Sitizens;
        this->House_Number = other.House_Number;
    }
    Home(Home&& other)
    {

    }

private:

    size_t Home_Floor = 0; //кол во этажей
    size_t House_Number = 0; // номер дома
    size_t Home_Apart = 0; // количество квартир
    size_t Home_Sitizens = 0; // количество жильцов

    bool bHave_Basement = false; // есть ли подвал
    bool bHave_Parking = false; // есть ли парковка
    bool bOn_Left = false; // на левой или правой стороне улицы false = правая : true = левая

};
```

Comment: стандарт считает, что собственный конструктор копирования выключает автоматический оператор присваивания. пока-что его можно просто дописать `Home & operator =(const Home &) = default;`

Comment: то есть если я делаю конструктор копирования, то обязан делать оператор присваивания?

Comment: я его делаю, так как это сказано в задании

Comment: Как ее получить, вашу ошибку? https://ideone.com/rCqtiM — где она?

Comment: https://ideone.com/boCijW @Harry

Comment: @AlexGlebe Вот для того и существует требование минимального компилируемого примера, которым пренебрег ТС... Как и правилом большой пятерки :)